# nginx PPA does not work?

Tags: 10.04, package-management, ppa, add-apt-repository

I want to use the newest version of nginx, so I wanted to add the nginx/stable ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable
sudo apt-get update
```

However, the upgrade command says that there are no upgrades available and nginx is still the old version. Did I do something wrong?

I use Ubuntu server 10.04 Lucid

add-apt-repository output:

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:nginx/stable
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /etc/apt/secring.gpg --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 8B3981E7A6852F782CC4951600A6F0A3C300EE8C
gpg: requesting key C300EE8C from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key C300EE8C: "Launchpad Stable" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
```

apt-cache policy ouput:

```
$ sudo apt-cache policy nginx
nginx:
  Installed: 0.7.65-1ubuntu2
  Candidate: 0.7.65-1ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 0.7.65-1ubuntu2 0
        500 http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/universe Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: can you please add the output from the `add-apt-repository` command ? Also after running `apt-get update` can you please run `sudo apt-cache policy nginx` and post the result ?

Comment: I think this is a problem with the ppa. For example the file [Packages](http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/stable/ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/binary-i386/Packages) in the http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/stable/ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/binary-i386/ is empty. Same also for other architectures (as seen in http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/stable/ubuntu/dists/lucid/Release)

Comment: Are you facing the problem with any other ppa ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The packages in the `ppa:nginx/stable` appear to have been updated on September 29/30 2010.

Currently, version 0.8.52-0ppa1 is available for both lucid and maverick. As can be seen from the Build Status column [here](https://edge.launchpad.net/~nginx/+archive/stable/+packages). Both of these packages have successfully built.

The reported issue with the Packages file is also [no longer valid](http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/stable/ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/binary-i386/Packages). If you run `sudo apt-get update` and then attempt to either upgrade or install the nginx package (with `ppa:nginx/stable` added by `add-apt-repository`), you should end up with version 0.8.52-0ppa1.

As was mentioned earlier, the issue was with the PPA, not add-apt-repository. This can be confirmed by verifying that the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx-stable-lucid.list` file exists.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with the nginx/stable ppa.

The [ppa status page](https://launchpad.net/~nginx/+archive/stable) indicates it failed to build. That could explain why the ppa is not having binary packages, and therefore apt-get can't find suitable versions to install.

You could ask the ppa maintainers about the build failure.

Answer (score 0):

Yup... I made a mistake. I broke it once more recently. It's fixed now and as far as I can tell there's only one issue during upgrades between specific versions in a narrow window. I'm looking into how to properly resolve this but I'm not perfectly sure how yet. Either way, it affects a very low number of people (my guess about 20ish).

It should be all nice and good for a long time now. Thanks for bearing with us through a huge number of changes. :)